# AG Grid add valueFormatter to defaultColDef

Tags: ag-grid

According to the [AG Grid Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-definitions/), defaultColDef contains properties that all columns will inherit and default columns can specify any of the [column properties](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-properties/), which includes the valueFormatter.

However when I do this...

```
  const valueFormatter = function (params) {
    const [suffix, label] = params.value;
    return suffix+" "+label;
  };

  const columnDefs = [];
  for (let node of pathNodes) {
    columnDefs.push({
      field: node.id(),
     });
  }

  const defaultColDef = {
    editable: false,
    filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
    cellRenderer,
    valueFormatter, // this gets ignored
  };

  const gridOptions = {
    rowData,
    columnDefs,
    defaultColDef,
    autoSizeStrategy: { type: "fitCellContents" },
  };

 grid = agGrid.createGrid(gridEle, gridOptions);
```

...I get this warning:

> AG Grid: Cell data type is "object" but no value formatter has been provided. Please either provide an object data type definition with a value formatter, or set "colDef.valueFormatter"

However it works perfectly fine when I reference the valueFormatter from within the columnDef elements like this instead:

```
  for (let node of pathNodes) {
    columnDefs.push({
      field: node.id(),
      valueFormatter,
    });
  }
```

AG Grid is included as `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>`, which is currently on version v31.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:-

```
const defaultColDef = {
    editable: false,
    filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
    cellRenderer,
    valueFormatter: valueFormatter, // this gets ignored
  };
```